# :last and .last don't return the same thing since jQuery 2.1

Tags: jquery

Just encountered a bug in our code as a result of a change in the results of using the :last filter in jQuery 2.1 (migrating from 1.8)

If we change it to use .last() it works as it did previously.
I understood that these should return the same thing, albeit in slightly different ways.
Is this a bug or can it be explained?

Here's some sample HTML

```
<div id="root">
<span class="k-in k-state-selected k-state-focused">
    <img class="k-image" alt="test" src="">test</span>
</div>
```

And some jQuery :last vs .last() returning different results:

```
var lastFilter = $('#root').find('> .k-in').contents(':last')
var lastFunction = $('#root').find('> .k-in').contents().last()

console.log('lasterFilter=', lastFilter);
console.log('lastFunction=', lastFunction);
```

Show the console in your browser and run this fiddle to see the different return values.

http://jsfiddle.net/VfuLL/

Comment: Does `.contents()` still take any arguements? See [here](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).

Comment: Probably that's because the `last` selector is only applied to the nodes that have  `nodeType` of `1`.

Comment: @j809 I hadn't checked that, that could be it - I didn't get a migration warning though (using migrator)

Answer (score 1):

1. `last` selector in Sizzle (jQuery selectors engine) applies only to elements, I think element is a node, which has `nodeType` 3
2. `$('#root').find('> .k-in').contents().last()` return last element in the set, which was created by `contents`, which return set of matched elements, **including text** and comment nodes. In you case text is last:

> ```
> <div id="root">
>     <span class="k-in k-state-selected k-state-focused">
>         <img class="k-image" alt="test" src=""/>
>         test
>     </span>
> </div>
> ```

So it's not a bug, it a feature :)

Comment: Right, I'll have to confirm, then, as this must have changed. Because if you set your jQuery library to 1.8.3, on the Fiddle page above, they both return exactly the same thing - ie just the text. The question, then, is was it "corrected" jQuery 2.1 (after 1.8.3) or could one be considered a bug?

Comment: thanks, though I'd need a confirmed source, some bug report discussion, for example, to be really confident that it's a correction